# Blade conditional rendering when a variable exists and is true

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I would like to conditionally add an attribute and a class to a blade component, when a parameter is set to true. When the parameter is not set, I would like it to be evaluated to falsy.

The condition is the following:

- If the parameter is (defined and) set to true, render the class
- If the parameter is false **or undefined**, do not render the class

View:

```php
@include('my-component', ['disabled' => true])
@include('my-component') /* implicitly: disabled = false */
```

Component:

```php
<button
    {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : ''}}
    class="{{ $disabled ? 'Button--disabled' : ''}}"
>
Button
</button>
```

This code is throwing an `Undefined variable: disabled` for the case when the parameter is not explicitely set to false (undefined). The only way I managed to make it work is to set the disabled parameter to false, like this:

```php
@include('my-component', ['disabled' => false])
```

For readability and maintenance reasons, I would like to omit this `disabled => false`, as this is the default state.

How should the Component code be changed, in order to keep the same syntax in the view?

Answer (score 2):

Blade component can accept props and then based on props class can be added

For anonymus component

```
@props(['disabled' => false])
<button 
    {{
        $atttributes->merge([
            'disabled' => $disabled,
            'class' => $disabled ? 'Button--disabled' : ''
        ])
    }}
>
    {{ $slot }}
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good! I wonder why is `$atttributes->merge([...])` necessary? Would it be possible to get rid of it but assign a default value to the `$disabled` in case it's not defined?

Comment: Yes its possible $attributes->merge() allows to have default attributes and also merge attributes defined when component is used. Eg: `<x-my-component class="foo" />` foo will be merged/added to the class list. Default value is assigned to $disabled when declaring `@props(['disabled' => false])`

Comment: I see. In my case the component is not declared like `<x-....>` components. It just uses `@include` syntax so it seems that using `@props` does not work in that case.

Comment: Laravel components are great for your use case https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components You can even have a full class to act a Controller sort for component view. Have a look at the docs

Comment: Does "Lavarel components" refer to the `<x-...>` syntax or to the `@include` syntax? For this project I don't want to use the `<x-...>` syntax with the controller file because it's too verbose. I am not PHP dev so I find the docs difficult to navigate :/ Maybe the best option in this case would be to not omit falsy parameters values

Comment: Laravel Blade components do not necessarily need a corresponding "Controller kind of" class. Anonymous components are just like partial views which by convention are located within `resources\views\components` directory. The snippet in my answer is a complete functional anonymous Blade component. By convention to use it `<x-my-component></x-my-component>` syntax is used. Never tried but should work with `@include` However for such small anonymous components using `<x-..>` is not bad at all I think